# using chrome os as client in vmware fusion

Tags: macos, google-chrome, vmware, virtualization

I've been wracking the net for several days on this topic. i want to run Chrome OS virtualized in VMWare Fusion on my mac. While it seems Parallels Desktop has a quick and easy method for running Chrome, the same can't be said for VMWare.

the most common resource for Chrome OS builds is http://chromeos.hexxeh.net, but it hasn't been updated in years. Meanwhile a new source — http://arnoldthebat.co.uk/wordpress/chromium-os/ — provides images for VirtualBox and as .img, neither of which I've had any luck getting to work. despite attempts to dd the images to USB disks, or convert the .vdi files to .vmdk, the results are always the same: "no operating system found" when VMWare tries to boot.

it would seem there ought to be a community resource for providing containers, or appliances, that VMWare can run with the latest builds of ChromeOS. if anyone knows of such a source, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

The system administration is hard stuff. Don't worry. The best you can do is ask here or even elsewhere -because the problem is about the configuration, not Mac-. Download the iso / img from the official repository. Then create a new virtual machine. Configure the settings as you wish (RAM, disk size) and then when disk image requested, select the downloaded one. If it also asks you what OS are you trying to run, try (because Chrome OS may not be displayed) to select it.

This process is universal. The thing is that since the iso contains the boot and kernel, the virtual machine should at least know which files correspond to each function. It may be impossible to boot it if VMW doesnt recognize them. In that case, if you still wanna run VMW -which would be hardcore- I can just tell you to surf the net.

The easiest EVER is in that case using parallels. Download a cracked copy or buy it if you are a legal guy 😉.

Hope it helps

Edit: **And the link you provided is vanilla, not chrome OS. So thats kind of help to install it, which is fine, but in that case you should also take a look at the docs. Did you download the file for vmw? It should work**

Comment: Where do you find the "official repository"? I wasn't specific enough to say that I'm talking about Chromium OS, not Chrome. Which file is for VMWare? Can you provide a link?

Comment: @AaronVegh once you reach de vanilla page, scrill down where it has a table. Choose the version you want and click on its link. Its on the page you provided. It should work

Comment: Okay, I'm assuming you mean http://chromium.arnoldthebat.co.uk — as I said in my question, I can't get the images from here (neither the .vmi nor .img) to work. Both VMWare and VirtualBox fail to load them.

Comment: @AaronVegh no, im talking about http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/

Comment: Ah. Well, as I said in my question, those images haven't been updated since April 2013! Hexxeh retired from performing that service, and ArnoldTheBat took over. I'd like to run a current version of ChromiumOS.

Comment: If you dont find any compiled one, you have to compile it yourself from downloading the source code from chromium.org

Comment: @AaronVegh Sorry i forgot to mention look at my previous comment